# how to get the newest commit where in master

Tags: git, github

I'm the beginner of git.
So, I have a question about git.
I create a branch of mine
I use `--rebase master` & `merge` to add my commit that my branch at master branch.
And now I checkout to my branch.
I don't know how to get the merge version in my branch.
Thanks.

Comment: Please show the actual command(s) you used.  It's hard to help someone without enough context about what they've done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its very easy to get updated code on your branch
first checkout your branch

```
git checkout branchname
```

after that

```
git pull origin master
```

this way you will get updated code from master to your branch

Comment: Why sudo? You should configure your rights correctly in your working dir.

Comment: Do **not** use sudo here!  There is no need for it to run as **root**!

Comment: Thanks all to answer my question.

Comment: @BenoîtLatinier  if there is any permission issue then use sudo or else let it be

Comment: @Mayank Jha: The default should *not* be using sudo. This is another issue, and not relevant in the question. It suggest git needs more privileges to work when it shouldn't and thus encourages bad behaviors like always ask for more privileges. And it can causes problems since files created using sudo will be owner by root...